# Upload files to azure blob storge in chunks using sas url but while uploading i am getting 403 error

Tags: javascript, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I am generating sas url using python for example sample sas url is

```
https://testvideos.blob.core.windows.net/testvideos/user_125/video_125/test.mp4?se=2023-05-14T11%3A02%3A59Z&sp=rc&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=7o8tNK508ekXy9JpahWBsfdfsfPjdtjWwN6etNk%3D
```

for this generated sas url i am making put request through react js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const uploadBlocks = async (file, sasUrl, blockIds) => {
  const blockSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4MB block size (adjust as needed)

  const totalBlocks = Math.ceil(file.size / blockSize);
  const promises = [];

  console.log("Uploading blocks...");

  for (let i = 0; i < totalBlocks; i++) {
    const blockId = blockIds[i];
    console.log(blockId);
    const start = i * blockSize;
    const end = Math.min(start + blockSize, file.size);
    const blockContent = file.slice(start, end);

    const promise = fetch(`${sasUrl}&comp=block&blockid=${blockId}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": file.type,
        "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
      },
      body: blockContent,
    });

    promises.push(promise);
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);

  console.log("Blocks uploaded successfully.");
};

const commitBlockList = async (sasUrl, blockIds) => {
  const xmlPayload = `
    <BlockList>
      ${blockIds.map((blockId) => `<Latest>${blockId}</Latest>`).join("\n")}
    </BlockList>
  `;

  console.log("Committing block list...");

  const response = await fetch(`${sasUrl}&comp=blocklist`, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/xml",
      "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
    },
    body: xmlPayload,
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    console.log("Block list committed successfully.");
  } else {
    throw new Error("Failed to commit block list");
  }
};

const FileUploader = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    if (!file) {
      return;
    }

    const blockSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4MB block size (adjust as needed)
    const totalBlocks = Math.ceil(file.size / blockSize);
    const blockIds = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < totalBlocks; i++) {
      const blockId = btoa(`block-${i}`);
      blockIds.push(blockId);
    }

    const sasUrl =
      "https://testvideos.blob.core.windows.net/testvideos/user_125/video_125/test.mp4?se=2023-05-14T11%3A02%3A59Z&sp=rc&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=7o8tNK508ekXy9JpahWBsfdfsfPjdtjWwN6etNk%3D";

    try {
      await uploadBlocks(file, sasUrl, blockIds);
      await commitBlockList(sasUrl, blockIds);
      console.log("File upload completed successfully.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("File upload failed:", error);

      // Handle the specific error when the request is unauthorized
      if (error.message === "Failed to commit block list") {
        console.error("Failed to commit block list. Please make sure the SAS URL is properly authorized and the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly, including the signature.");
        // Handle the error appropriately (e.g., display an error message to the user)
        } else {
        console.error("Unexpected error:", error);
        }
        }
        };
        
        return (
        <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
        <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button>
        </div>
        );
        };
        
        export default FileUploader;
```

but while uploading file i am getting the following errors

403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)

Failed to commit block list. Please make sure the SAS URL is properly authorized and the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly, including the signature.

I think i am missing in the authorisation headers or sas urls?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you only have `read (r)` and `create (c)` permissions in your SAS token/URL. In order to commit block list, you would need `write (w)` permission in your SAS token/URL.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#permissions-for-a-directory-container-or-blob):

[image]

Please create a new SAS token/URL with `Read (r)` and `Write (w)` permissions (you do not need to have `Create (c)` permission there) and retry your code. You should not get this error.